# Passing values to another activity via intent

Tags: android

I am trying to pass some values via intent and show them in a new activity. I have tried many solutions but the problem is always the same: There are two textviews in new activity and when I set the text via code but only the textview tv2 appears.

Please help. I am new to android and java and trying to learn the concepts for a new app.

MainActivity.java:

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Details.class);
            intent.putExtra(NAME, name);//name is string type
            intent.putExtra(VALUE, value);//value is long type

            startActivity(intent);
```

Details.java :

```
    TextView tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
    TextView tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.value);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String name = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.NAME);
    Long value=intent.getLongExtra(MainActivity.VALUE, 0);
    String value_text=value.toString();
    tv1.setText(name);
    tv2.setText(value_text);
```

Layout For Details.java(Image is for further experiments):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textSize="40sp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<TextView        
    android:id="@+id/value"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textSize="20sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Log the values you get from the Intent in `Details.java`, you probably get that right, but have a problem displaying your textview tv1, which is a layout problem, not a code problem.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I am adding the layout code. Please have a look. I can' figure out where is the problem in it.

Comment: @Kam Post the value for name?

Comment: What are the values of the `NAME` and `VALUE` constants?

Comment: @Hariharan  sorry I don't understand your question.Can you please explain

Comment: Small style point: `Long value=intent.getLongExtra(MainActivity.VALUE, 0L);` (add L to make 0 a constant of type long)

Comment: @DanielGabriel the value for both NAME and VALUE constants is NULL

Comment: @Kam that is your problem. Make them static public final Strings with any old thing you like in them e.g. `static public final String NAME = "NAME";`

Comment: So you define them in your `MainActivity` class like `public final String NAME = null;`? Try giving them a unique value, like: `public final NAME = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName() + ".Name";

Comment: @RobP thanks, it worked. I saw on one tutorial to use NULL. Now I get it. Thanks again...

Comment: Check if name is not null/empty while putting in intent